# try a SQL query, and return text on success

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`mysql_query($insert,$con);`
that's what i have...how can i make it `echo` "success" upon success and the sql_error on failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (mysql_query($insert,$con))
  echo "Success";
else
  echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
```

Comment: You can not access result resource with this

Comment: This code works what @tekknolagi wants. mysql_errno() and mysql_error() return error number and text of the error message from previous MySQL operation, right?.

Comment: this result was most helpful, @Shakti, and it worked exactly as needed. thank you.

Comment: @tekknolagi: If it is select query how you retrieve result?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Agree, nothing handles result of mysql_query() operation, but that was not original question. Yes, this makes sense only for testing query end do exactly what @tekknolagi wants - prints out error message if failed or "success" if everything's ok. I understand that you mean something like `$res=mysql_query('QUERY')` but handling result was not part of original question.

Comment: No, That is still part of original question. In order to handle errors you are discarding the result resource. Is this any kind of good technique to handle errors. In doing some stuff under control you are lossing the result. That is bad

Comment: No, it **is NOT** good technique to handle errors, you're absolutely right. Sometimes you should consider that all of us do not think same way because we are all different. I got your point in first comment, but obviously you did not get mine. However, @tekknolagy found this useful and if this helps him, why we continue to argue this way? Cheers